# Too few arguments for printf()

Tags: php, errors

I'm having a problem making this printf print the time & date correctly within my theme. I keep getting "Too few arguments."

```
<span class="entry-date"><abbr class="published" title="<?php the_time('Y-m-d') ?>"><?php unset($previousday); printf( __( '%1$s &#8211; %2$s', 'erudite' ), the_date( '', '', '', true ) ) ?></abbr></span>
```

I have two strings in the printf(). %1$s and %2$s are meant to correspond to the_time and $previousday. Is:

```
<?php the_time('Y-m-d')?>
```

not serving here as a printable string? Or did I not form this correctly? Am I missing something obvious/subtle? It's been many years since I coded in PHP, and I'm rusty. TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
printf( __( '%1$s &#8211; %2$s', 'erudite' ), the_date( '', '', '', true ) )
```

expects two strings; you've only offered one (`the_date()`).  If you want to use two strings, you have to give it two strings.

If you want `printf()` to use `the_time()` and `$previousday`, you need to *tell* it so:

```
printf( __( '%1$s &#8211; %2$s', 'erudite' ), get_the_time(), $previousday );
```

for instance.

Comment: Ahh...I forgot to call it. My brain freeze. Thank you.